# Kivy crashes. Don't know why

Tags: kivy

Firstly I know this is not specific, but right now I am unable to figure out why, so I'll edit question when I have the reason. Sorry!.

I'm starting with Kivy, and I have lots of questions, but in this case, I have not even an error message!

Here is the code, this is just an adaption of the Pong Game tutorial, but using just one .py file (with no .kv file):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class PongBall(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = "ball"
        velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
        velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
        velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
        self.canvas = Ellipse(pos=(Window.width*0.5, Window.height*0.5), size=(50,50), Color=(1.0, 1.0, 0.5))
        #self.canvas.add(Ellipse(pos=(width*0.5, height*0.5), size=(50,50), Color=(1.0, 1.0, 0.5)))#This way doesn't works

    def move(self):
        print "move called"
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.center = self.center
        self.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
        print "ball served"


class PongGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        mainLayout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        ball = PongBall()
        ball.id = "pong_ball"
        ball.center = Window.center
#        mainLayout.add_widget(Rectangle(pos=(Window.width*0.5, 0), size=(10, Window.height)))#Unresearched error.
        mainLayout.add_widget(Label(id="playerOneScore", font_size=70, center_x = Window.width*0.25, top=Window.height-50, text="0"))
        mainLayout.add_widget(Label(id="playerTwoScore", font_size=70, center_x = Window.width*0.75, top=Window.height-50, text="0"))
        mainLayout.add_widget(ball)
        print "Hello"
        ball.serve_ball()

    def update(self, dt):
        print "updated!"
        ball.move()

        # bounce off top and bottom
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.heightt):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        # bounce off left and right
        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        print "game created!"
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)#Clock statement neverminds for the error.
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

Somebody experienced in Kivy able to understand why Kivy crashes with this code?

I'm using python 2.7.9 and Kivy 1.10.1

Comment: Why don't you have an error message? What is printed in the console when you run this code?

Comment: There is no error!. It just crashes with no error!. Os prompt: pythonw.exe stopped working (I'm using python idle)

Comment: @Reaversword execute your code from the CMD, there you will surely get error information, on the other hand IDLE has many limitations especially in the GUIs

Comment: Same results with "python main.py" from cmd or from powershell. Not even a clue.

Comment: So when you write `python main.py` you get literally no output at all? As if you had just pressed enter without even typing anything?

Comment: There are some "control" prints to know where code is flowing (you can read it in the code, as 'print "ball served"'. After some "control" prints, Os promp with the crash.

Comment: I have a similar issue with 'from kivy.core.window import Window'. If you comment that line and dependent parts of your code, does your app run then?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the slash at:
`from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\ ObjectProperty`
you don't need a new line for it and don't tab near object property.